# Is it possible to connect an esp32 (or similar) to a "guest" WiFi network that requires logging in via a splash page?

Tags: wifi, esp32

I would like to connect an IoT device (esp32, etc.) to the guest WiFi network at the office. When I connect my own personal laptop to the guest network, it requires checking a box on a splash/welcome page indicating that I agree to some terms (no looking at pornography, no plotting to overthrow the government, etc.) and clicking a button to log in. Is it possible for an esp32 to do that automatically?

Comment: it may be possible

Comment: Are you talking about a generic solution or to get by a specific login page?

Comment: Does the captive portal (that’s the name of such a page) include any CAPTCHA or similar robot/human detection?

Comment: A better solution is to talk to you IT department about either white-listing the ESP's mac address or deploying a separate IoT network.

Comment: No, there is no sort of CAPTCHA on the page.

Comment: I am specifically trying to get past the login page at the office guest network. I don't know if it is possible to program the ESP to do that or not.

Comment: `I don't know if it is possible` ... only one way to find out

Comment: There is rarely "only one way" when it comes to programming...or anything for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "It may be possible"

But without access to the network to read the page source and do a little network sniffing we can't answer with any more certainty (it may be simple POST, it may need a whole bunch of other factors).

And as I've already said in the comment, talking to your IT department is a better approach, they may be able to just white list the ESP's MAC address so it doesn't need to accept the T&Cs.

While building shadow IT systems can be a lot of fun (hell, I've done it at some pretty big places) and asking for forgiveness is often easier than permission, you do need to know what you are doing to ensure it is at least basically secure, because if you are the cause a breach, the hammer will fall on you.